# Writing a spark dataframe to Azure Sql Server is causing duplicate records intermittently

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

We are using JDBC option to insert transformed data in a spark DataFrame to a table in Azure SQL Server. Below is the code snippet we are using for this insert. However, we noticed on few occasions that some records are being duplicated in the destination table. This is happening for large tables. e.g. if a DataFrame has 600K records, after inserting data into the table, we get around 620K records. This is very rare occurrence, but we still want to understand why that's happening.

```
DataToLoad.write.jdbc(url = jdbcUrl, table = targetTable, mode = "overwrite", properties = jdbcConnectionProperties)
```

Only reason we could think of is that while inserts are happening in distributed fashion, if one of the executors fail in between, they are being re-tried and could be inserting duplicate records. This could be totally meaningless but just to see if that could be an issue.

Comment: I don’t fully understand this but I came across this jira item. It is on quite an old version now but may still be of interest. https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SPARK-16741

Comment: This isn't an answer but rather a possible workaround: Use the [Spark connector for Azure SQL Database and SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/sql-databases-azure) instead of the JDBC extensions.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? What was the outcome? I have a similar issue (just with different provider), at the end of the insertion, database will contain more rows then there is on the spark side.